Tomcat on Openshift: KeyManagerFactory instance not obtained
I try to create KeyManagerFactory.getInstance using SunX509 or PKCS12. Both cases it says that Error initializing key manager factory (algorithm not supported). in order to connect to another application using the SSLContext. Please share solution clue.
Noteé The server.xml is also configured for Keystore and TrustStore for SSL based authentication. And, the web access through SSL works fine.
I tried changing the type, but never worked.
